LiquiBase Postgres default-schema
I have this problem in my application.yaml and in my postgres database: in my database I have a schema called TRIAL in uppercase. When the application starts it does not find the schema and fails, as it is looking for it in lower case.
liquibase:
  change-log: classpath:/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml
  default-schema: TRIAL
  enabled: true

The return error
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: schema "trial" does not exist
Has anyone had the same problem? I've already tried inserting single quotes and double quotes, the result is the same.
Marco

Are you sure what is exception provide liquibase, not jpa?
Could you add all log?

@sgtgroove did you try adding objectQuotingStrategy=QUOTE_ALL_OBJECTS

I solved it using this:
System.setProperty("liquibase.preserveSchemaCase", "true");

in the main class
